# How can I pivot with several counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

I am trying to monitor some DQ on some ID's and I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | Flag 1 | Flag 2 | Flag 3 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Error |  |  | January |
| 002 |  | Error | Error | January |
| 003 | Error | Error |  | January |
| 001 | Error |  |  | February |
| 002 | Error |  |  | February |
| 003 |  | Error |  | February |
| 001 | Error | Error | Error | March |
| 002 |  |  |  | March |
| 003 | Error | Error | Error | March |
| 001 |  |  |  | April |
| 002 |  | Error |  | April |
| 003 |  |  | Error | April |

and would like to pivot it like this:

| - | January | February | March | April |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Flag1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Flag2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Flag3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

So far I have tried it like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    Account, date, Flag1, Flag2 
    from  Main_Table  
    where Flag1 is not null and len(Rule_Account_Name) >1
) Accounts
PIVOT (
  count(Account)
  FOR date in ([2021-08-21],[2021-09-21],[2021-10-22],[2021-11-22],[2021-12-31],[2022-01-31],[2022-02-28])
) AS PivotTable
```

I appreciate the help, the point would be to monitor the number of errors each month for each of the flags to be able to rank the flags to put more effort in fixing the top 3 worst flags

Comment: Looks like you need to unpivot first then pivot. Sample data *as text* would help immensely

Comment: Provide text instead of pictures

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hey  @Charlieface unfortunately the table has been designed like that and it's not a pivot like so. So would I be still capable of unpivoting it?

Comment: I don't understand the logic for March, it should be `2,2,2`?

Comment: @Charlieface yes, you are right, the second table should be the sum of all errors

Answer (score 3):

You need to first *un*-pivot the data so that you can get the `Flag` values into rows, then pivot the months into columns.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      [Flag 1],
      [Flag 2],
      [Flag 3],
      Date
    FROM Main_Table mt
) mt
UNPIVOT (
    FlagValue FOR FlagName IN (
        [Flag 1],
        [Flag 2],
        [Flag 3]
    )
) u
PIVOT (
    COUNT(FlagValue) FOR Date IN (
        January,
        February,
        March,
        April
    )
) p;
```

You can also replace `UNPIVOT` with `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` and replace `PIVOT` with conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  u.FlagName,
  January  = COUNT(CASE WHEN Date = 'January'  THEN FlagValue END),
  February = COUNT(CASE WHEN Date = 'February' THEN FlagValue END),
  March    = COUNT(CASE WHEN Date = 'March'    THEN FlagValue END),
  April    = COUNT(CASE WHEN Date = 'April'    THEN FlagValue END)
FROM Main_Table mt
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('Flag 1', [Flag 1]),
    ('Flag 2', [Flag 2]),
    ('Flag 3', [Flag 3])
) u(FlagName, FlagValue)
GROUP BY
  u.FlagName;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a746bba183b5ec42b8f05ded849af39f)